# String Array OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

In an app I'm writing, I'm loading an XML  into a Java String[], then turning each item into an object and adding these to an array of objects.

Below is my code:

The Java part, with a do-while loop

```
ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> list = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
    ArrayList<ExpandListChild> list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
    ExpandListGroup gru1 = new ExpandListGroup();
    gru1.setName(getString(R.string.album_vancouver));
    String[] tempArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.album_array_vancouver);
    int count = 0;
    int max = tempArray.length;
    do {
        ExpandListChild ch = new ExpandListChild();
        ch.setName(tempArray[count]);
        ch.setTag(null);
        list2.add(ch);
    } while(count <= max);
    gru1.setItems(list2);
    list.add(gru1);
```

And the arrays in XML

```
<string name="album_vancouver">Vancouver</string>
<string name="song_vancouver_1">Future Wars</string>
<string name="song_vancouver_2">A Word Of Welcome And Of Warning</string>
<string name="song_vancouver_3">See You In Vancouver</string>
<string name="song_vancouver_4">To Withstand The Force Of Storms</string>
<string name="song_vancouver_5">He Is Here, He Is Not Afraid</string>
<string name="song_vancouver_6">The Surgeon And The Scientist</string>
<string name="song_vancouver_7">Fairmount</string>
<string name="song_vancouver_8">Untitled</string>
<string-array name="album_array_vancouver">
    <item>@string/song_vancouver_1</item>
    <item>@string/song_vancouver_2</item>
    <item>@string/song_vancouver_3</item>
    <item>@string/song_vancouver_4</item>
    <item>@string/song_vancouver_5</item>
    <item>@string/song_vancouver_6</item>
    <item>@string/song_vancouver_7</item>
    <item>@string/song_vancouver_8</item>
</string-array>
```

I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` at runtime, at the line "list2.add(ch)".
What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have infinite loop there, you are not incrementing the `count` variable inside the do-while statement.

Use `ch.setName(tempArray[count++]);`

Also, the while condition should be `count < max`, otherwise you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.